# Update variable based on time passed

Tags: javascript, html, time, setinterval

I currently have the following code:

```
<div id="resource1"></div>
<div id="resource2"></div>
<div id="resource3"></div>


<script>

var resource1 = 50;
var resource2 = 50;
var resource3 = 50;

var modifier = 3;

function resourcesupdates() {
    setInterval(function() {
            resource1 = resource1 + modifier;
            resource2 = resource2 + modifier;
            resource3 = resource3 + modifier;
            document.getElementById('resource1').innerText = resource1;
            document.getElementById('resource2').innerText = resource2;
            document.getElementById('resource3').innerText = resource3;

            console.log(resource1);

     }, 1000);
}

resourcesupdates();
</script>
```

This code works because ever second the resources are updated by 3 per second.

What if I wanted to have it update at a rate of 47 per minute, however I wish for it to output to the user only when the resource is updated by a whole number, not every second as that would result in decimal values?

Comment: The problem is, that when updating by 47/60 per second, you might never reach a point where the number has no decimal places. Would it meet your requirements to always just display the rounded number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment above: The problem is, that when updating by 47/60 per second, you might never reach a point where the number has no decimal places. If it still meets your requirements when the number is just always rounded for display, this could be your solution:

```js
var resource1 = 50;
var resource2 = 50;
var resource3 = 50;

var modifier = 47; // per minute

function resourcesupdates() {
    setInterval(function() {
            resource1 = resource1 + modifier/60;
            resource2 = resource2 + modifier/60;
            resource3 = resource3 + modifier/60;
                        
            document.getElementById('resource1').innerText = Math.round(resource1);
            document.getElementById('resource2').innerText = Math.round(resource2);
            document.getElementById('resource3').innerText = Math.round(resource3);
     }, 1000);
}

resourcesupdates();
```

```html
<div id="resource1"></div>
<div id="resource2"></div>
<div id="resource3"></div>
```

If you want to always round down, as requested in your comment to the other question, just replace `Math.round()` by `Math.floor()`.

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I was after!

Comment: Glad to hear! Just updated the question to show what you'd need to do four always rounding down, as per your comment to the other answer.

Comment: Is there a way to update the display to be every second, not every 47/6000?

Comment: But you explicitely asked for an update *only when the resource is updated by a whole number, not every second*?

Comment: You can set the timeout to 1000 again and in the function change `modifier/6000` to `modifier/60`, if that's what you want?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what a part of the code was doing, that's my bad. Your answer is fine as it is, thank you very much! :D

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Actually, due to inaccuracy of JavaScript timers, it was adding the number a bit too fast. I updated the code to do as I said in my comment above, so its more accurate (but might take a tiny amound longer between updating the numbers).

Comment: How inaccurate are they? Is it detrimentally bad or not really?

Comment: It reached 97 after ~50-55 seconds, but with the updated version it's pretty accurate now.

Answer (score 3):

Updated Answer

```
<div id="resource1"></div>
<div id="resource2"></div>
<div id="resource3"></div>


<script>

var resource1 = 50;
var resource2 = 50;
var resource3 = 50;

var modifier = 47/60;


function resourcesupdates() {
    document.getElementById('resource1').innerText = resource1;
    document.getElementById('resource2').innerText = resource2;
    document.getElementById('resource3').innerText = resource3;
    setInterval(function() {
            resource1 = resource1 + modifier;
            resource2 = resource2 + modifier;
            resource3 = resource3 + modifier;
            if (Number.isInteger(resource1) ) {
                document.getElementById('resource1').innerText = resource1;
            }
            if (Number.isInteger(resource2) ) {
                document.getElementById('resource2').innerText = resource2;
            }
            if (Number.isInteger(resource3) ) {
              document.getElementById('resource3').innerText = resource3;
                        }
            console.log(resource1);

     }, 1000);
}

resourcesupdates()
</script>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbr139/jf0e3b6u/
Just havent seen it update by a whole number yet...

Comment: I want it to update every time the value of a resource changes by a whole number, not every 60 seconds

Comment: what about if what I wanted was for the value to round down upon display. So for example, the value is 15.7, but it continues to display 15, until it reaches 16 (like 16.1) and then it displays only 16. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes, my updated jsfiddle ended up being pretty much the same as the accepted answer: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbr139/jf0e3b6u/1/

Comment: No problem! You got there before me anyway :)